# convertir una cadena separada por (,) en una cadena separada por (.) en python

Tags: python

tengo la siguiente lista:

```
list=['jaeger', 'jaeger-span', 'jaeger-ell', 'FindTraces 385062 1583408544',
      'jaeger', 'jaeger-span', 'jaeger-query', 'FindTraces 70681 1583386032'],
```

y quiero convertirla a lo siguiente:

```
 list=['jaeger.jaeger-span.jaeger-ell.FindTraces 385062 1583408544',
       'jaeger.jaeger-span.jaeger-query.FindTraces 70681 1583386032'],
```

Comment: Entiendo que quieres unir por puntos cada 4 elementos de la lista y generar una nueva lista con los strings generados que contienen grupos de 4 elementos unidos por puntos. ¿ es así ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si he entendido bien la pregunta, quieres grupos de 4 elementos de una lista original unidos por puntos (`.`)

Por cierto, he cambiado el nombre de tu `list` a `lista` es muy mala idea utilizar como nombre de variable una palabra reservada de python: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-list

```
>>> lista_grupos = ['.'.join(lista[i*4:(i+1)*4]) for i in range(len(lista) // 4)]
```

La nueva lista quedaría según lo esperado:

```
>>> lista_grupos
['jaeger.jaeger-span.jaeger-ell.FindTraces 385062 1583408544', 'jaeger.jaeger-span.jaeger-query.FindTraces 70681 1583386032']
```

La función `'.'.join()` une listas de elementos por el separador indicado en el `str`, y con python puede extraer fragmentos de una lista indicado inicio (`index0`) y fin (`index1`): `lista[index0:index1]`

Answer (score 0):

Yo haría algo así. Espero que te sirva:

```
    separator="."
    testLIst = ["a","b","c"]
    separator.join(item for item in testLIst)

    #O directamente
    testLIst = ["a","b","c"]
    ".".join(item for item in testLIst)
```

Con éste código se concatenan todos los elementos de una lista con el separador que tú escojas siendo en este caso el separador el caracter ".".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Considera agregar una explicación de lo que hace tu código

Comment: Te dejo por aquí un enlace a GitHub a una función que hace esto y otros "códigos varios":  https://github.com/PRodenasLechuga/HackerRank/blob/master/Python/String-Split-and-Join.py

Comment: Considera poner el codigo del link en tu respuesta, puede no ser accesible a todos los usuarios o ser borrado en un futuro